# React functional components async props to children

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, use-effect

I have a functional component (`App.js`) where I want to fetch some initial data using `useEffect`.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const init = async () => {
      const posts = await getPosts(0, 3);
      const newArticles = await getArticles(posts);

      setArticles(() => [...articles, ...newArticles]);
    };

    init();
  }, []);
```

then I want to pass the result to a child

```
<ArticleList articles={articles}></ArticleList>
```

but in the `Article` component I get an empty array when I try to `console.log` the props.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(props.articles);
    setArticles(() => props.articles);
  }, [props.articles]);
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: What do you want to do while waiting for the data to load?

Comment: I would use promise in this case

Comment: nothing, i just want to list the articles when they are available

Comment: i don't understand why the articles the `ArticleList` component isn't showing the articles in the console after the promise is fulfilled

Comment: Maybe an issue with the api call, making it to return an empty array.